# Use Holo theme in Qt Android application

Tags: android, c++, qt, themes, qt5

I have a Qt Android application, and I want to set its theme to be Holo (i.e. the dark variant, not Holo Light). Here's a comparison between Holo Dark theme (left), and how my application looks now (right):

[image]
[image]

I'm using Qt 5.2.0, and I'm using Qt/C++ (i.e. not QML), but I'm interested for any way that works, regardless of Qt version or whether it's QML or C++.

**Edit:** I know that using Ministro, it will create pixmaps for all widgets using the "native" theme, but is it possible to tell Ministro **which theme** to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Holo Dark can now be selected as of Qt 5.4 by adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` to `<application>` in AndroidManifest.xml.

This works with Qt 5.4, but not with Qt 5.2, with Qt 5.2, the theme is always the phone's default theme no matter what you specify for `android:theme` in the manifest.

So in AndroidManifest.xml, find the `<application>` node, and change it to:

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" ...
```

---

This is not available for the moment for QtQuickControls, although it was brought to Qt 5.2 for the QtWidgets.

The former is on BogDan's TODO list for 5.3. See his blog for details:

[Qt on Android Episode 1](http://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-1/)

Here you can find a couple of screenshots from my friend's system.

#### Non-native

[image]

#### Native

[image]

#### QtCreator

[image]

Comment: Hi, I finally returned to that question, after a long hiatus (lol). This time I totally rewrote it to ask about Holo Dark explicitly, to avoid ambiguity about "native theme". Anyway, I'll clean up my comments, because the discussion became rather big now.

Comment: You don't need to be thanking me, you're the one who's answering :) Anyway, since I changed it about setting the theme explicitly, I assume simply using Ministro won't be enough, because it defaults to Holo Light theme, right?

Comment: I see there's an `AndroidManifest.xml`, can I set something there?

Comment: I just tested with Qt 5.4 and now it's working. I need to add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` property to `<application>`. If I compile with Qt 5.2 (same android manifest), it's not changing the theme to Holo Dark, though. So maybe they fixed something in Qt 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Bu using Ministro your application gets a dependency to the Ministro App. I think this is an disadvantage because the extra dependency will cause the Application to check on startup if Ministro is installed on your device yes or no. If it is not installed the user is forced to install it over the Android Play Store.

Instead of using Ministro I would set a custom stylesheet which imatetes the holo theme.

`QApplication::setStyleSheet(const QString & sheet)`

There is a repository on GIT [here](https://github.com/zmyaro/holo-web), which imitates the various android themes. It shouldn't be to difficult adapt a holo .css file to a Qt stylesheet (.qss) file.

Comment: So you mean that no such theme actually exists as of yet, unless I port it from CSS to QSS? How would I go about doing that? I see a git repo, so I download it, and then what? Where do I put the files? Do I compile them somehow?

Comment: I'm not aware of a QSS holo theme, but the internet is a big place so who knows something already exists. QSS and CSS are quite similar, see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html for more info regarding Qt QApplication::stylesheet files. You don't compile a CSS or QSS file. Just put the file in your project just as any other file, and load it for the entire application with the setStyleSheet method.

Comment: OK, but it seems that the CSS file does not mention Qt's widgets at all. If you want to set the style for QLineEdit for example, you need to have a line `QLineEdit {...}`. This CSS does not mention Qt widget types at all. I think it's not made with Qt in mind. I'll try loading it anyway, to see if it doesn't work by some miracle, but I doubt it.

Comment: It won't load because it doesn't have anything to do with Qt, it regards android css themes, hence you can use the styles to make your own qss file for Qt widgets. I've mentioned the css file to provide a guideline to an alternative approach, however you need to put some effort in to make it actually work for your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Style guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme), you need to set it into the AndroidManifest.xml:

> To set a theme for all the activities of your application, open the
>   AndroidManifest.xml file and edit the  tag to include the
>   android:theme attribute with the style name. For example:

```
 <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
```

If you want the light theme (the default one is the dark one), you have to write this instead:

```
 <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>
```

Comment: I tried putting the Theme.Holo line, but it didn't work, the theme remains the same, with white background. I created an AndroidManifest.xml file, and it looks like this - http://pastebin.com/LgXfP1RJ.

Comment: and try with:


<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />