# Wrong Qt Android theme

Tags: android, c++, qt, themes, qt5

I need to create Android application with Qt, but I can't find out how to make application look native.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3x2S.jpg

And I need it to be like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiBcm.jpg

I tried to change android:theme, but nothing changed.
I also looked in [Use Holo theme in Qt Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079613/use-holo-theme-in-qt-android-application), but it didn't helped too.
What should I do now? Help me, please.
I have latest Qt 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Fopr old Qt versions (pre 5.5 I would say), You need to deploy the application with Ministro Qt libraries. That will end up with the expected "look and feel".